# fireStore type does not match [String:any]

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

jumping into FireStore following the official documentation, trying to connect a Struct to Firestore/setdata functions, according to the documentation, Cloud Firestore converts the objects to supported data types and can handle custom classes

so the struct goes as follow :

```
public struct City: Codable {

let name: String
let state: String?
let country: String?
let isCapital: Bool?
let population: Int64?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
    case state
    case country
    case isCapital = "capital"
    case population
}
```

}

and uploading data as follow. Firestore wants a [String: Any] type of data :

```
 let city = City(name: "Los Angeles",
                state: "CA",
                country: "USA",
                isCapital: false,
                population: 5000000)

do {
    try db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData(city) // <--- Cannot convert value of type 'postData' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

} catch let error { 
    print("Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
}
```

any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the only way I found to connect custom Structs (or classes) is a bit ugly, but it works but defining the struct as follow

```
public struct City: Codable {

let name: String
let state: String

var DataToPass : [String:Any] {
    return [

        "name" : self.name,
        "state" : self.state

    ]


}
```

and then simply pass it to FStore using datapass :

```
let city = City(name: "Los Angeles",
                state: "CA")
db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData(city.dataToPass)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the data should look more like this:

```
        db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData([
            cityName: city.name,
            cityState: city.state,
            // And so on...
        ])
```

Those are Key:Value-Pairs. On the left side is the field name in FireStore and the right side the value that should be written in it.

Comment: yes of course you can hard plug it this way, and it works, but the documentation says firestore can connect to custom classes and structs, and their own example shows it doesnt.